# android shared preference getting error

Tags: android

i need to store user login and password details in shared preference but i am getting error. I need to maintain user login details in session. When user login user mail and password should be get stored in edit text. From next time user can click on login button to enter directly. What i need to do now. Here is my code. When i try below code i am getting unfortunately closed error. Where i need to modify the code. What is the problem in this code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b;
EditText email,password;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
String email1,passw;
SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
Editor toEdit;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

private boolean isValidEmaillId(String email){

    return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
              + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
              + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
              + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
              + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
              + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
     }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!isValidEmaillId(email.getText().toString().trim())){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            else if(password.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {           
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {

                 email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
                 passw = password.getText().toString().trim();

                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(Name, email1);
                editor.putString(Phone, passw);
                editor.commit();

                System.out.println("sharde    :" +Name+Phone);

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
                    "Validating user...", true);
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();                          
                    }
                  }).start();             
        }
        }
    });


}

void login(){
    try{            
        final User user = new User();

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://ip:8080/ActCFWeb/login"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email1));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",passw)); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        System.out.println(response);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.contains("success")){

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedBack.class);

          //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());

            Log.e("n", email.getText()+"."+ email.getText());

            startActivity(nextScreen);
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                     
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
return true; 
}
```

}

Comment: add stacktrace where you initialized sharedpreferences

Comment: how to add stacktrace

Comment: how did you initialized 'sharedpreferences' ? also post your logcat error here

Comment: Show initialize of shared preferences and logcat error

Comment: sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 added this

Comment: @benarjeebojja This will help you : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: but data is  not getting stored in edit text

Comment: Its simple bro.. just extract data from sharedpreferences and set it to EditText.

Comment: 'data is not getting stored in edit text ' dint get you waht actually you want post your complete class tell where you getting error

Comment: when i am printing it i am getting null in log cat

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that You call views methods from thread. You have login method in witch you probably call to `dialog` or other views .**You cannot access from not main thread to ui elements.** You have to use **handler** or **asynck task**.

Comment: now i dnt have that much time to handle with async task

Comment: You start  new activity from no UI thread. Create handler in your fragment, send messages from thread to handler and call all light operations on main thread. In login method in catch you call UI view  dialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

May be you are talking about this

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

```
            editor.putString(Name, email1);
            editor.putString(Phone, passw);
            editor.commit();

            System.out.println("sharde    :" +sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "def").toString()+ ", "sharedpreferences.getString(Phone, "def");
```

Comment: tnx. now i am getting databut i need to stick that data to edit text. how to do it??

Comment: what do you mean by stick data to edit text ? it will not clear text until you do it manually. According to your class file edit text never been cleared so data should be there as it was.

Comment: no.it is not happening.the data is cleared when i clear catche

Answer (score 0):

Getting values from SharedPreferences storage.

```
SharedPreferences  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String emailString = sharedPreferences.getString("email", null); 
String passwordString = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
```

In the onCreate method, first check whether the preferences has values for email and password.

```
 if((emailString != null) && (passwordString != null)) {
   //Populate the email and password edit texts using stored email and password values.
   etEmail.setText(emailString);
   etPassword.setText(passwordString);
 }
```

Starting an activity should be performed in main(UI) thread. You can use Handler or runOnUiThread.

```
if(response.contains("success")){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedBack.class);

               //Sending data to another Activity
                nextScreen.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());
                Log.e("n", email.getText()+"."+ email.getText());
                startActivity(nextScreen);
            }
        });
    }else{
        showAlert();                
    }
```